# R fill vector with same value until a different one is found

Tags: r, vector, fill

In R I have two vectors such as

```
2 NA NA  1 NA NA
1 NA  2 NA NA NA
```

And I would like them to be like

```
2 2 2 1 1 1
1 1 2 2 2 2
```

Any ideas?

Comment: See `zoo::na.locf` from the `zoo` package.

Answer (score 0):

With `tidyverse`:

```
 read.table(text="2 NA NA  1 NA NA
                  1 NA  2 NA NA NA")%>%
    t()%>%
   data.frame()%>%
   mutate_all(funs(as.numeric(.)))%>%
   fill(c(X1,X2))%>%t

   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
X1    2    2    2    1    1    1
X2    1    1    2    2    2    2
```

Answer (score 0):

vectors:

```
a <- c(2, NA, NA,  1, NA, NA)
b <- c(1, NA,  2, NA, NA, NA)
```

As anonymous function:

```
(function(x) {
    nai <- which(is.na(x))
    i <- which(!is.na(x))

    x[nai] <- x[i][findInterval(nai,i)]
    return(x)
 })
```

Call:

```
    (function(x) {
        nai <- which(is.na(x))
        i <- which(!is.na(x))

        x[nai] <- x[i][findInterval(nai,i)]
        return(x)
     })(a)
#[1] 2 2 2 1 1 1

    (function(x) {
        nai <- which(is.na(x))
        i <- which(!is.na(x))

        x[nai] <- x[i][findInterval(nai,i)]
        return(x)
     })(b)
#[1] 1 1 2 2 2 2
```